# Как убрать пикселизацию на стыках соседних фрагментов SVG?

Tags: html, svg, illustrator

Есть svg картинка, которую я поставил на фон. Всё бы ничего, если бы не эти стыки, я пробовал вплоть до 0,00001 пикселей редактировать. Но это не помогло.

Есть ли какие нибудь нейросети, или другие приспособления, которые могут убрать эту погрешность?

P.s. При этом, если сохранить эту картинку как Png, никаких стыков нет

[image: Стык]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привет всем у кого такая же проблема. Нашел решение.

Итак, повторяйте за мной.

1. Откройте иллюстратор
2. Выберите проблемный элемент
3. И в верхнем меню, Объект->Контур->Создать параллельный контур
4. Блокируете все не нужные слои для удобства, и оставляете, только те, между которыми есть проблема
5. Выбираете их
6. Выбираете инструмент "Создание фигур" (Shift+M)
7. И нажимаете на часть параллельного контура, которая вышла за пределы допустимого объекта
8. Теперь выберите инструмент "Выделение" (V)
9. Выберите элемент, который недавно выделили "Созданием фигур"
10. Удаляете этот элемент с помощью "delete" или "Backspace"
11. Также, чтобы не загружать файл, ненужными элементами, выберите то, что было в самом начале, и также удалите
12. Профит!

Upd. Забыл сказать, элемент который вы выбрали для "Параллельного контура", нужно поставить Под другой проблемный элемент чтобы не было казусов, что "Параллельный контур" налезает на объект

Upd 2. Если ваш файл не состоит из большого кол-ва объектов, а также вам просто надо выровнять стыки, используйте [вариант Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115563/300769). Но тк мне его вариант не подошел, использую свой

Answer (score 6):

### Теоретический ответ

Если вы хотите, чтобы ваш SVG был максимально резким, спроектируйте его так, чтобы его формы, особенно горизонтальные и вертикальные части, находились на границах пикселей.

Например, сравните следующие два примера:

```html
<svg width="50" height="50">
  <rect x="9.5" y="9.5" width="31" height="31"/>
</svg>

<svg width="50" height="50">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30"/>
</svg>
```

Вот, как это выглядит при увеличении в 4 раза.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый раз, когда ваша фигура проходит через середину пикселей, вы получите серые пиксели из-за сглаживания, которое используют 2D рендереры.

Можно использовать атрибут SVG **`shape-rendering="crispEdges"`** для отключения сглаживания браузером. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering

> **crispEdges**
>
> Указывает на то, что браузер должен попытаться акцентировать на
>   контрасте чистых краев рисунков, в ущерб скорости рендеринга и
>   геометрической точности. Для достижения наилучшего результата четкости
>   края, браузер может отключить сглаживание для всех линий и кривых или,
>   возможно, только для прямых, близких к вертикальным или
>   горизонтальным. Кроме того, браузер может скорректировать позиции
>   строк и ширину линий для выравнивания краев с пикселями устройства.

```html
<svg width="50" height="50">
  <rect x="9.5" y="9.5" width="31" height="31" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/>
</svg>

<svg width="50" height="50">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="30" height="30"/>
</svg>
```

Картинка увеличена в 4 раза

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Серых пикселей, как в первом примере не наблюдается

Универсального, 100% решения проблемы пикселизации нет.

Так как 2D рендеринг зависит от установленной операционной системы, её настроек, видеокарты и какой используется браузер.

*Вы можете использовать комплексный подход:*

1. Использовать целочисленные значения координат SVG изображений
   Если вы берете готовое изображение с дробными значениями, то можно обработать его [SVG оптимизатором](https://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor)
2. Установить целочисленное значение `viewBox`
3. Использовать атрибут  `shape-rendering ="crispEdges"`
4. Если возможно изменение дизайна, - избегать контрастных пограничных цветов.
   Например: вместо черно-белого сочетания используйте темно серый цвет или вместо чисто белого фона используйте оттенки серого цвета.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect вот это добавь ещё

Comment: @MaximLensky не, это из другой оперы, линия не меняет свою толщину при изменениях масштаба

Comment: да точно но рваные края убирает

Comment: @MaximLensky вполне возможно, толщина линии не изменяется и в определенных случаях помогает

Comment: Саша что такое pathLength ?

Comment: нее... это атрибуте svg но он ни работает https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength

Comment: `<path d="M 0,50 h100" pathLength="10" stroke="red"/>` не ясно

Comment: я сам допетрю ...:)) из за мелочи не задаюсь вопросами

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Да, это может помочь в некоторых случаях. Но в моём, оно только заостряет на этом внимание, и делает стыки более заметными. Единственное решение ТАКОЙ проблемы, это убрать какое либо расстояние между объектами. Так что, я думаю лучше сменить название обратно.

Comment: @DarkRou А из-за чего у вас возникают рваные края? Вот именно из-за пикселизации. Одно изображение отодвинуто от другого и есть места для появления полутонов

Comment: @Alexandr_TT вот что происходит если добавить это https://imgur.com/a/AgyL2G8

Comment: @DarkRou вполне возможно, факторов влияющих на пикселизацию очень много, почитайте мой ответ. Поэтому надо выбирать решение для каждого конкретного случая. Вот на вашем ПК смотрится ваше решение хорошо, но на другом будет смотреться плохо. Всё зависит от браузера, ОС, видеокарты, разрешения дисплея. Поэтому пикселизация более точное название, чем рваные края